# Freeswitch can't find my softphone user details

Tags: freeswitch

I've installed freeswitch and I'm following this

http://www.onlinesolution.co.nz/viewtopic.php?t=102

to add a softphone user. I had it connected so I could test dial the tetris theme (9891) and it all worked but when I restarted freeswitch it now says

2012-07-19 11:25:37.882544 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:1989 Can't find user [1000@MY_IP]
You must define a domain called 'MY_IP' in your directory and add a user with the id="1000" attribute
and you must configure your device to use the proper domain in it's authentication credentials.

I don't know what I've changed to make it behave differently. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue and solved it by changing the IP addresses in the internal and external sip profiles.

```
/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/sip_profiles/internal.xml  
/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/sip_profiles/external.xml
```

So in internal.xml I changed `$${local_ip_v4}` to `192.168.16.50` (freeswitch machines LAN IP).
And `external.xml`, `$${local_ip_v4}` to the external IP address (connecting to the internet).

Explained in the FreeSWITCH Wiki:
[Multi Home Tutorial](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Multi+home+tutorial), ["Setting the SIP profiles to use different Ethernet ports"](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Multi+home+tutorial#Multihometutorial-SETTINGTHESIPPROFILESTOUSEDIFFERENTETHERNETPORTS)