# FusionPBX External Sip Profile Conf INVALID

Tags: voip, freeswitch, pbx, fusionpbx

I was having the exact same problem as this guy.I followed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12496797/1221203) but that gives me
**`INVALID Profile`**

I have only tried to configure external.xml file to my External IP.But everytime i `reloadxml` it tells me my sip profile conf is invalid

What i tried:

- Made sure that the ports are not blocked
- Can reach the port from telnet command `telnet MY_IP MY_PORT`

Please throw some light anyone.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

I was changing the wrong xml tag.Needed to change

```
<param name="ext-rtp-ip" value="MY_EX_IP"/>
<param name="ext-sip-ip" value="MY_EX_IP"/>
```